# Install zabbix default tables on mysql with error 1046

Tags: mysql, raspberrypi, zabbix

I tried to install zabbix on my raspberry pie with [this tutorial](https://linuxhint.com/install_zabbix_raspberry_pi/) but I am stuck a installing the default tables.
Half way in it says that I should run this command:

```
$ zcat /usr/share/doc/zabbix-server-mysql*/create.sql.gz | mysql -u zabbix -p
```

I get asked for a password but after that I get this:

```
ERROR 1046 (3D000) at line 1: No database selected
```

What did I miss here?

Edit: the command `zcat /usr/share/doc/zabbix-server-mysql*/create.sql.gz` alone does work and prints a bunch of SQL commands. But why doesnt it work with both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to specify which database to create the tables on:

```
 zcat /usr/share/doc/zabbix-server-mysql*/create.sql.gz | mysql -u zabbix -p zabbix
```

This assumes that the database name is zabbix, as listed in the tutorial.